# Op Amp summing the circuit is not behaving as desired

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image: Schematic]

The first op amp's output is 18 V and second's output is 27 V but when I sum those two outputs with a summing op amp, it gives -8.53 V at output. What is the wrong with my circuit? Am I not supposed to read "45 V" at output?

R1 = 1k, R2 = 1k, (non-inverting amplifier)

R3 = 2k, R4 = 1k, (non-inverting amplifier)

R5 = 1k, R6 = 1k, R7=1K (adder)

Comment: You are certainly not supposed to see a voltage outside the op-amp supply rails!

Comment: Is the simulation model behind those op-amps an ideal op-amp model or a real circuit model of a '741?

Comment: It's ideal I think..The simulation software is ISIS.

Answer (score 2):

The adder circuit does add but it inverts the summation about the voltage applied to it's non-inverting input. So an input of A and an input of B becomes C - (A plus B), where C is the voltage on the non-inverting input.

Another problem is that none of the opamps have power rails connected.